# Como comparar uma string com um datarow

Tags: .net, vb.net

esse é o código:

```
Dim clientesCadastrados As DataTable = MnipulaDB.ConsultaSql("SELECT CAMPO1 AS NOME FROM TAB_CLIENTES WHERE CAMPO21 =1")
For Each cliente As DataRow In clientesCadastrados.Rows
 If campo3.texto <> cliente.ToString Then
     MessageBox("Cliente não cadastrado!")
     Return
 End If
Next
```

Um erro retornado diz que um DataRow não pode ser transformado em String. Como posso fazer essa comparação do `campo3.texto` com `cliente.ToString`?

Comment: Você precisa fazer comparação mas, traz uma lista de itens de um Datatable correto, a sua SQL não está errada?

Comment: Isso, preciso comparar a string da caixa de texto ```campo3``` com os nomes resultantes no DataTable clientesCadastrados. Acabei de debugar aqui e o sql está funcionando. O problema é que não está sendo possível comparar uma string com um datarow.

Comment: se tentou `cliente["NOME"]`?, ou seja, especificar o campo! a sua SQL poderia ser um `count(*) as c` o que acha?

Comment: tentei, essa sintaxe não funciona com vb.net :/

Comment: porque é assim `cliente("NOME")`, CONFUDI com C#

Comment: opa, funcionou! muito obrigado @novic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que especificar em qual coluna estão os clientes... Esse código abaixo vai funcionar se seus clientes estiverem na primeira coluna (index 0)

```
Dim clientesCadastrados As DataTable = MnipulaDB.ConsultaSql("SELECT CAMPO1 AS NOME FROM TAB_CLIENTES WHERE CAMPO21 =1")
For Each linha As DataGridViewRow In clientesCadastrados.Rows
 If campo3.texto <> linha.Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
     MessageBox("Cliente não cadastrado!")
     Return
 End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma solução que eu tenho usado num projeto recente que desenvolvi em que era +- o que tu pretendes:

```
For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim i2 As Integer
            For i2 = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count
                If tbEncomenda.Text = dr(i2 - 1) Then
                    X = X + 1
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,20}", dr(i2 - 1))
                    Console.Write(X)
                End If
                Console.Write(X)
                tbEncomenda.Text = tbEncomenda.Text & "_" & X
            Next i2

        Next
```

O que eu faço aqui é correr a tabela inteira e verificar a existencia de uma string com aparencias iguais e, se sim, incrementar na variavel X

PS: ds é um dataSet e dr é uma dataRow